# Performance optimizations of LineBreakMeasurer

Tags: java, text, kotlin, awt

I am currently writing a text block with syntax highlighting in OpenGL and to layout my lines correctly with line wrapping I am using AWTs `LineBreakMeasurer`. The visual results are perfect, the performance is OK, however I was wondering if there are possibilities to make it a bit faster. Currently it takes on average 2-3 milliseconds for one line of text to be laid out.

So this is the code that is currently used to do the layout

```
private fun calculateLineLayout(line: AttributedString, graphics: Graphics2D, width: Int, layouts: ArrayList<TextLayout>): Float {
    val iterator = line.iterator
    if(iterator.beginIndex >= iterator.endIndex) {
        return 0.0f
    }

    val end = iterator.endIndex
    val measurer = LineBreakMeasurer(iterator, graphics.fontRenderContext)
    measurer.position = iterator.beginIndex

    var sizeY = 0.0f
    while(measurer.position < end) {
        val layout = measurer.nextLayout(width.toFloat())
        layouts.add(layout)
        sizeY += layout.ascent + layout.descent + layout.leading
    }

    return sizeY
}
```

My questions would be

- Are there alternatives to `LineBreakMeasurer` from AWT that are more efficient?
- Could there be optimization potential from the fact, that the font will always be monospaced and therefore the number of characters in a line is already deductible from the width?